# setjmp and longjmp implementation in mmix

Tags: assembly

I've written an implementation of setjmp and longjmp in MMIX (assuming no name mangling).
I also hand-assembled it.
Are there any mistakes anyone can spot?

```
    // Memory stack pointer is stored in $254.
    // jmp_buf is rO, next address after setjmp call, memory stack pointer,
    // frame pointer, then possibly other data (for sigsetjmp/siglongjmp).
    // rG is preserved over a longjmp call
    // (not that it should change over one, anyway)
setjmp IS @
    GET    $1,rO            // FE01000A
    STOU   $1,$0,0          // AF010000
    GET    $1,rJ            // FE010004
    STOU   $1,$0,8          // AF010008
    STOU   $254,$0,16       // AFFE0010
    STOU   $253,$0,24       // AFFE0018
    POP    0,0              // F8000000
longjmp IS @
    LDOU   $254,$0,0        // 8FFE0000
    SAVE   $255,0           // FAFF0000
    GET    $1,rG            // FE000013
    // why 15? We save 13 special registers, two local registers,
    // and the number 2, as well as any global registers.
    // That's 256-rG + 16, and we add only 15 because $255 is the address
    // of the saved rGA.
    SETL   $0,271           // E300010F
    SUBU   $1,$1,$0         // 26010100
    SLU    $1,$1,3          // 39000003
    // now $255 is topmost saved register, $255+$1 is bottommost such,
    // $254 is rO after.
    SUBU   $0,$254,$1       // 2600FE01
    LDOU   $2,$255,$1       // 8E02FF01
    STOU   $2,$0,$1         // AE020001
    INCL   $1,8             // E7010008
    PBNZ   $1,@-12          // 5B01FFFD
    SET    $255,$0          // C1FF0000
    UNSAVE 0,$255           // FB0000FF
    // now we have restored rO, but not other stuff
    LDOU   $253,$0,24       // 8FFD0018
    LDOU   $254,$0,16       // 8FFE0010
    LDOU   $0,$0,8          // 8F000008
    PUT    rJ,$0            // F6040000
    POP    2,0              // F8020000
```

The register stack was the hard part here. Everything between the `SAVE` and the `UNSAVE` inclusive is essentially just “set register stack pointer properly”; after that it takes no time at all to fix up the other registers and return.

If you have any other questions, I'm happy to explain my reasons for each tetra of that code.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. Does the code work as expected?

Comment: @pacmaninbw Haven't checked, not having a MMIX interpreter at hand (currently rewriting Knuth's to be faster, using compiler intrinsics/inline assembly and uint64_t instead of structs). But it should. I'm asking if anyone else can see issues.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `setjmp` takes the `jmp_buf` parameter as `$0` - but how is `jmp_buf` defined - how much space does it need for example?

Also `longjmp` takes 2 parameters - the same `jmp_buf` and an `int` - I don't see `$1` being used for the second input parameter in your `longjmp`

You can find commandline tools to run MMIX programs at https://mmix.cs.hm.edu/exe to try out your implementation - there's a Windows GUI debugger too - could you show sample MMIX code that calls your `setjmp` and `longjmp`?

Comment: jmp_buf would be octa[5], the last octa of which is used only for sig(set|long)jmp.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't see `$1` being used for the second input parameter"?

Comment: calling `setjmp`: set `$(X+1)` to the address of a `jmp_buf`, then `PUSHJ $X,setjmp` (or arrange for `$Y` to be the address of `setjmp`, then `PUSHGO $X,$Y,0`). The return value appears in `$X`, and locals, `$253`, and `$254` will be unaltered. (As usual, locals `$(X+1)` and up disappear.)

Comment: calling `longjmp`: set `$X+1` to the address of a `jmp_buf`, `$X+2` to the return value for the `setjmp` that set it, and `PUSHJ $X,longjmp` (or, again, arrange for `$Y` to contain the address of `longjmp` then `PUSHGO $X,$Y,0`). There will be no return.

Comment: longjmp gets its second parameter in $1 - caller $X+2 - where is $1 used for the return for setjmp?

Comment: Right at the end of `longjmp`: `SET $0,$1; POP 1,0`. Which I will be changing to `POP 2,0` just to be cheap.

Comment: But that assumes UNSAVE has restored $1 - after what looks like edits to the saved context - I don't think this can work or is allowed - SAVE and UNSAVE are mainly meant for the operating system to perform context switching - Knuth does say "Coroutines might, of course, be sufficiently complicated that they each do require a register stack of their own. In such cases MMIX's SAVE and UNSAVE operations can be used, with care, to save and restore the context needed by each coroutine" - but I believe the saved state is meant to remain opaque

Comment: Did you see exercise 16 in section 1.4.1' of Fascicle 1, MMIX? (Nonlocal goto statements.) Sometimes we want to jump out of a subroutine, to a location that is not in the calling routine. For example, suppose subroutine A calls subroutine B, which calls subroutine C, which calls itself recursively a number of times before deciding that it wants to exit directly to A. Explain how to handle such situations when using MMIX's register stack. (We can't simply JMP from C to A; the stack must be properly popped.)

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to run your code with MMIX tools - you'll be able to see SAVE and UNSAVE in action and check your implementation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123481/discussion-between-nolongerbreathedin-and-zartaj-majeed).